# hibernate schema validation wrong column but using normal int

Tags: java, hibernate

Working with hibernate I'm stuck on a schema validation issue. The error is pretty straightforward, it says the expected column type and actual found ones in my code don't match.

Except that as far as I can see they do match. I've added columnDefinition="int(10)"  after looking at similar questions, but this doesn't help. Any help or pointers what to look at further would be much appreciated.

**Class  definition and variable declaration**

Traject class

```
public class Traject implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id", columnDefinition="int(10)")
private int id;

@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "traject")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "toets_bij_traject")
@JsonBackReference
@OrderBy("toetsInSerie ASC")
private Set<ToetsBijTraject> toetsenBijTraject;

other vars and methods not shown
```

ToetsBijTraject class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tt_traject_ref_toets")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="")
public class ToetsBijTraject implements Serializable, Comparable<ToetsBijTraject> {

@Id
@Column(name = "traject_id")
private Traject traject;

@Id
@Column(name = "toets_id")
private Toets toets;

other vars and methods not shown
```

**Table traject**

```
CREATE TABLE `traject` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_actief` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `naam` (`naam`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tt_traject_ref_toets` (
`traject_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`toets_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`traject_id`,`toets_id`),
KEY `toets_id` (`toets_id`),
CONSTRAINT `tt_traject_ref_toets_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`traject_id`)REFERENCES `traject` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `tt_traject_ref_toets_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`toets_id`) 
REFERENCES `ref_toets` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Error message:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [traject_id] in table [tt_traject_ref_toets]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [tinyblob (Types#VARBINARY)]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:105)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:92)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
... 87 more
```

Comment: add ToetsBijTraject mapping too please

Comment: @Zeromus Added it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sometimes when adding object as a type you need to add the type on the mapping as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate is complaining not about Traject but about `tt_traject_ref_toets`

`wrong column type encountered in column [traject_id] in table [tt_traject_ref_toets]`

It's a mapping mistake:

the `ToetsBijTraject` is mapping an associative table. 
You can either use the @ManyToMany mapping (only in case where you have only the id columns) 
or you have to change the mapping to this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tt_traject_ref_toets")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="")
public class ToetsBijTraject implements Serializable, Comparable<ToetsBijTraject> {

@Id
@Column(name = "traject_id")
private int trajectId;

@Id
@Column(name = "toets_id")
private int toetsId;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("trajectId")
private Traject traject;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("toetsId")
private Toets toets;
```

The MapsId tells hibernate that those are pk/fk and its the same as declaring 
@JoinColumn("trajectId", insertable=false, updatable=false)

You can find some good explanation here

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Also you have no need of `columnDefinition`

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get it too work like this and let you know.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The answer itself is comprehensive and the link helped me understand what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you need the explicit `columnDefinition="int(10)"` for the int type. My suggestion is removing that and let Hibernate generate the tables by setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` or `update`.

See also: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html

Comment: Hi Nguyen, I don't need that, I tried adding that to see if it would help since almost every other question about this error says this will fix it. Thanks for your input.